# Comment option disappears after posting and deleting a comment on mobile site

Tags: bug, comments, mobile-web

Today I'm adding a comment then deleting because it got muddled and my phone screen is bugging out.

After deleting, the 'Add Comment' link disappears until I refresh the page.

I'm guessing this is a bug. I'm using a Nexus 5 not updated to latest Android version if that matters.

Comment: Some bugs are active for years so yes, hundreds of bugs get no response.

Comment: Thanks @shadowwizard, I thought it was a new bug because I'd never noticed it in my 3+ years here. By the same token, I also thought it might be an easy fix if it was caused by a recent update.